# I have created a login form and the rating system I do not know why still see error

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

my problem is `"spin" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)`

```py
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound 

#........................................................... 
bad=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
#........................................................... 

def song1(): 
    playsound('g:/song1.wav') 

def song2(): 
    playsound('g:/song2.wav') 

def rate(): 
    print(spin.get()) 

#........................................................... 

window=Tk() 
window.title("login form") 

#code 
def sign(): 
    if (user.get()=="alireza" and pas.get()=="ramz"): 
        master=Tk() 
        master.title("Alireza's App") 
        Label(master,text="Welcome Alireza",font=("courgette",25),fg="lime").pack() 
        master.geometry("800x680") 
        window.destroy() 
        Label(master,text="").pack() 
        Label(master,text="this is my first app with python TK i hope you enjoy!",fg="gold",font=("courgette",17)).pack() 
        Label(master,text="").pack() 
        btn1=Button(master,text="sound 1",bg="lime",width=15,height=2,command=song1) 
        btn1.pack() 
        btn2=Button(master,text="sound2",bg="lime",width=15,height=2,command=song2) 
        btn2.pack() 
        Label(master,text="").pack() 
        Label(master,text="please rate me (from 1 to 10:bad , from 11 to 20:medium , from 21 to 30: good , from 31 to 40:perfect)",fg="red").pack() 
        spin=Spinbox(master,from_=1,to=4) 
        spin.pack() 
        Button(master,text="rate",command=rate).pack() 
        Label(master,text="").pack() 
        Button(master,text="quit",bg="red",width=25,height=2,command=master.destroy).pack()
        master.mainloop() 
    else: 
        lbl.pack() 
        
#......................................................................................... 
Label(window,text="username",fg="orange",font=("tahoma",16)).pack() 
user=Entry(window) 
user.pack() 
Label(window,text="password",fg="orange",font=("tahoma",16)).pack() 
pas=Entry(window) 
pas.pack() 
Label(window,text="").pack() 
btn=Button(window,text="Enter App",width=15,height=2,command=sign) 
btn.pack() 
lbl=Label(window,text="username or password is incorrect",fg="red") 
#end 
window.geometry("300x200") 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of posting a link to an image

Comment: Add `global spin` at the start of the `sign` function.

Comment: thanks the lizzard

Comment: @alininja83 for an explanation please read Nick's answer. Also if it helps consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define Spin in the function. You only did in Line 41 as a local variable so you cant acces it from the "rate" function you created. You could create a Parameter for your function that passes the spin object to solve your problem